# Kusto Query to Filter and calculate the Time difference between rows

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

| Timestamp | Correlationld | EventName |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-12T14:10:49.387Z | 02a9407f-3e2a-448c-961a-67c83d63720a | HandlingRequest | <-- 1a |
| 2022-04-12T14:21:47.797Z | 02a9407f-3e2a-448c-961a-67c83d63720a | RequestComplete | <-- 1b |
| 2022-04-12T14:25:28.748Z | 0455a17f-098a-4204-bf21-459280603f53 | HandlingRequest |  |
| 2022-04-12T16:09:09.066Z | 017fac2a-2d7b-496a-aed8-36265674c19a | HandlingRequest | <-- 2a |
| 2022-04-12T19:19:02.076Z | 01aba138-470f-406f-927c-1055c3776231 | HandlingRequest |  |
| 2022-04-12T21:30:22.943Z | 005dab40-b601-4f5d-a983-8a92945af909 | HandlingRequest | <-- 3a |
| 2022-04-12T23:19:45.32Z | 00676b81-cb5d-4847-b0de-328a3346c7e7 | HandlingRequest |  |
| 2022-04-12T23:25:28.291Z | 00574df8-5c92-4667-8566-62dabf65208a | HandlingRequest |  |
| 2022-04-12T23:48:28.306Z | 02d078c2-739b-460b-9fa9-776f7f97b863 | HandlingRequest |  |
| 2022-04-12T23:50:18.577Z | 043117f6-c972-423a-8368-f0476e89ed9f | HandlingRequest |  |
| 2022-04-12T23:53:36.762Z | 008cbb4c-21ca-421e-890f-335320d4e922 | HandlingRequest |  |
| 2022-04-13T00:00:26.387Z | 005c4b88-7d14-48ba-b292-65e3a0971405 | HandlingRequest |  |
| 2022-04-13T00:03:51.262Z | 02fd7cb9-0307-4eef-8d5c-dbd7f67199a7 | HandlingRequest |  |
| 2022-04-13T00:04:37.902Z | 02a3fd47-e73e-4305-bcea-9b4ce3743cbb | HandlingRequest |  |
| 2022-04-13T00:05:52.555Z | 03777fcd-c43b-41cf-969f-aad87f3a7318 | HandlingRequest |  |
| 2022-04-13T00:12:13.579Z | 00159845-9089-4671-bb93-fdce974ce804 | HandlingRequest |  |
| 2022-04-13T00:23:13.138Z | 005dab40-b601-4f5d-a983-8a92945af909 | RequestComplete | <-- 3b |
| 2022-04-13T08:09:14.458Z | 017fac2a-2d7b-496a-aed8-36265674c19a | RequestComplete | <-- 2b |
| 2022-04-13T13:02:08.395Z | 0142b2f2-032b-49d7-bcdf-fe0b1c32ef93 | HandlingRequest |  |

Refer attached image for the sample data table. I have correlation Id´s with 2 types of event names. Not all Correlation ID has both event name. I need to calculate the time difference between Handling request and Request complete for the correlation ID´s . Is there a way to filter only the ID´s that has these event names and calculate time diff. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two quick ways I can think of -

```
let t = datatable (Timestamp:datetime,Correlationld:string,EventName:string)
[
     "2022-04-13 00:12:13.5790", "00159845-9089-4671-bb93-fdce974ce804", "HandlingRequest"
    ,"2022-04-12 23:25:28.2910", "00574df8-5c92-4667-8566-62dabf65208a", "HandlingRequest"
    ,"2022-04-13 00:00:26.3870", "005c4b88-7d14-48ba-b292-65e3a0971405", "HandlingRequest"
    ,"2022-04-12 21:30:22.9430", "005dab40-b601-4f5d-a983-8a92945af909", "HandlingRequest"
    ,"2022-04-13 00:23:13.1380", "005dab40-b601-4f5d-a983-8a92945af909", "RequestComplete"
    ,"2022-04-12 23:19:45.3200", "00676b81-cb5d-4847-b0de-328a3346c7e7", "HandlingRequest"
    ,"2022-04-12 23:53:36.7620", "008cbb4c-21ca-421e-890f-335320d4e922", "HandlingRequest"
    ,"2022-04-13 13:02:08.3950", "0142b2f2-032b-49d7-bcdf-fe0b1c32ef93", "HandlingRequest"
    ,"2022-04-12 16:09:09.0660", "017fac2a-2d7b-496a-aed8-36265674c19a", "HandlingRequest"
    ,"2022-04-13 08:09:14.4580", "017fac2a-2d7b-496a-aed8-36265674c19a", "RequestComplete"
    ,"2022-04-12 19:19:02.0760", "01aba138-470f-406f-927c-1055c3776231", "HandlingRequest"
    ,"2022-04-13 00:04:37.9020", "02a3fd47-e73e-4305-bcea-9b4ce3743cbb", "HandlingRequest"
    ,"2022-04-12 14:10:49.3870", "02a9407f-3e2a-448c-961a-67c83d63720a", "HandlingRequest"
    ,"2022-04-12 14:21:47.7970", "02a9407f-3e2a-448c-961a-67c83d63720a", "RequestComplete"
    ,"2022-04-12 23:48:28.3060", "02d078c2-739b-460b-9fa9-776f7f97b863", "HandlingRequest"
    ,"2022-04-13 00:03:51.2620", "02fd7cb9-0307-4eef-8d5c-dbd7f67199a7", "HandlingRequest"
    ,"2022-04-13 00:05:52.5550", "03777fcd-c43b-41cf-969f-aad87f3a7318", "HandlingRequest"
    ,"2022-04-12 23:50:18.5770", "043117f6-c972-423a-8368-f0476e89ed9f", "HandlingRequest"
    ,"2022-04-12 14:25:28.7480", "0455a17f-098a-4204-bf21-459280603f53", "HandlingRequest"
];
// Option 1
t
| summarize diff = anyif(Timestamp,EventName == "RequestComplete") - anyif(Timestamp,EventName == "HandlingRequest") by Correlationld
| where isnotnull(diff);
// Option 2
t
| partition hint.strategy=native by Correlationld 
(
  order by Timestamp asc 
| project Correlationld, diff = Timestamp - prev(Timestamp) 
| where isnotnull(diff)
)
```

`Result set 1`

| Correlationld | diff |
| --- | --- |
| 005dab40-b601-4f5d-a983-8a92945af909 | 02:52:50.1950000 |
| 017fac2a-2d7b-496a-aed8-36265674c19a | 16:00:05.3920000 |
| 02a9407f-3e2a-448c-961a-67c83d63720a | 00:10:58.4100000 |

`Result set 2`

| Correlationld | diff |
| --- | --- |
| 005dab40-b601-4f5d-a983-8a92945af909 | 02:52:50.1950000 |
| 02a9407f-3e2a-448c-961a-67c83d63720a | 00:10:58.4100000 |
| 017fac2a-2d7b-496a-aed8-36265674c19a | 16:00:05.3920000 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA5WVS2vkRhDHzxmY79D4ZINL213Vr1LwaQnklEDIbcmhn7sT5uGMZQeHfPjU2HIGZ7NYRn1Rq/XTX/96bdukJnWjaprkytumLn/d7NrdlHa3o2y2Se6uPx6Ox7ZN0%20aw39bxbjpu9p%20vf3ho%20%20mntGvzxtV69Wm9%20k5doEYEbcGQ0no0OBoaXGB9ca0utDaOo3XAOjJYHwzkzAS9lsbBlha1PZ37Me3rVqC/tD/uRc2FgK/PYFRII7oR44BsZrALtvYIrjAK2AeIznvwWFPu3qGO6W3wk2JZ6AeK4QVcbI4RQjUWbMwJMsonvGuUNAdjtVuk2IwkYBzY0gtYpFkN2WsDtrsKiSNBTIxsXeqseaFicUM8NhTfBZ6BHw%207222b2v95bHi0biDUM9gHn6OBkoVpow2QdW1AGBOR9SW0sDB4jkbyQ/A4g2PJ2RZAUxJYNA0i6w5ETr5dbWPEJVYYGjWOOg7E7hlsLGbs8pwwg%20Uqikvt0JvOphC2zrREsfGjZlmD9n4Gh54KJsAaTmCfILUagTx65yWRDS9Lt3gCGztYF98Ffit4EjlZGgcdXhSnnCRFwAZx1mrfgTEUMNq5QkFCQWZpgdiRwsB6Dh4m6lVyoQVqIMntxOOWgCWgjYIlCe0ij%201o9Gj5XHmY2OogadDED2tjAfYmgQ8lUvUUUC/w%20AksxWfDEPh94AUFYuOpCZGePcaqQywIgViC53UG7olB3O2hc8jRL0i3Z4%20lRsyALwWCvYaSWfJYB7CtdYjVFai5hi5NlDktqLxnsBsdDs7NBSKRD71UKJZEsSmSFZ47pFRj6JQCmbi0pKXXR2n0s8eWjKSyh8JB%20jFSgkg%20Qtc2%20Ba5Ve5Lg/fU6IOdC8Q6l4QMmuOpV8ix3FH6nGOMEgfq7hse//b9evXhg/r59jTHlFmvpvXqb3V3v9ul4%20avpuqmdxmFaf%2046ecpeJ5z6ubm65y4UvDGG/8VcqXyo3o1UU8y/vzSjk1t7vaHaX%20/3V6exFy9Eoyz4Nt0nDZPO182%202mQ4Stj%20vPjzV5oD%200ruFqvLtcrpQ7H2o6np//qVOmuqCfi8fB7K9Pr965f/DifBznZHs4/eqW%20qXy9uvoHkcUosVsIAAA=)

Comment: Thanks it works perfect. I tried the Option 1.

Comment: I am sorry my bad. I thouht I clicked it unknowingly. I corrected it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works for you:

```
datatable(Timestamp:datetime, CorrelationId:string, EventName:string)
[
    datetime(2022-01-01), "a", "HandlingRequest",
    datetime(2022-01-01), "b", "HandlingRequest",
    datetime(2022-01-01), "c", "HandlingRequest",
    datetime(2022-01-02), "c", "RequestComplete",
    datetime(2022-01-01), "d", "HandlingRequest",
    datetime(2022-01-01), "e", "HandlingRequest",
    datetime(2022-01-01), "f", "HandlingRequest",
    datetime(2022-01-03), "e", "RequestComplete",
    datetime(2022-01-04), "b", "RequestComplete",
]
| order by CorrelationId asc , Timestamp asc 
| extend Correlated = prev(CorrelationId) == CorrelationId and EventName  == "RequestComplete" and prev(EventName) == "HandlingRequest"
| project CorrelationId, HandlingRequest = prev(Timestamp), RequestComplete = Timestamp, Correlated
| extend Diff = RequestComplete - HandlingRequest
| where Correlated | project-away Correlated
```

| CorrelationId | HandlingRequest | RequestComplete | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b | 2022-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 2022-01-04 00:00:00.0000000 | 3.00:00:00 |
| c | 2022-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 2022-01-02 00:00:00.0000000 | 1.00:00:00 |
| e | 2022-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 2022-01-03 00:00:00.0000000 | 2.00:00:00 |